# Does "Go to next loop iteration" stop thread?

Tags: loops, testing, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter to read csv file and i'm setting "Test action" with option "Go to next iteration" when EOF and i dont want to stop thread. If run over for loop, i want my script go to next "Transaction controller" below. But seems that thread will be stoped when run go to this "Test action".
Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) configuration instead of Test Action to stop reading from CSV,

Mark both `Recycle on EOF?` and `Stop thread on EOF?` as `false`

> Recycle on EOF? Should the file be re-read from the beginning on reaching EOF? (default is true) Yes
>   Stop thread on EOF? Should the thread be stopped on EOF, if Recycle is false? (default is false)

Also in JMeter 5 you can use [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) which replaced `Test Action` and choose `Break Current Loop` if your CSV inside a loop

Comment: I choose all option as your comment but thread is always stop when go to test action. it's not do transaction controller below loop

Comment: @AlexLe Remove `Test Action`

Comment: If remove this, how to break the loop?

Comment: Use JMeter 5's Flow Control Action `Break Current Loop`

Answer (score 0):

`Go to next loop iteration` assumes [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration, it doesn't break the loop of other [Logic Controllers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#logic_controllers),  if you want to go through all entries in the CSV Data Set Config and continue you can put your CSV Data Set Config under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and use the following condition:

```
${__groovy(!vars.get('myVar').equals('<EOF>'),)}
```

The CSV Data Set Config should be configured as follows:

[image]